# Changing the format of numbering theorems using thmtools and amsthm

Tags: numbering, indentation, thmtools

As the the title suggests, I want to have something like **Corollary 1.I** (first corollary of the first chapter)

I want the chapter counter be in Arabic numbers, and the corollary counter be in Roman numbers.

Before, when I was using `ntheorem`, I used to use the command `\theoremnumbering{Roman}`.

I tried to read what `thmtools` documentation suggest, but I can't understand.

my corollary environment is simply defined as follows:

```
\declaretheorem[
    name=Corollary,
    numberwithin=chapter ]{cor}
```

If you can help me also with the equivalence of `\theoremindent` (it adds margin to the `theorem` environment). If there is not a simple equivalence, I will pose that as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the Corollary environment `cor` is defined you can reset the number by redefining `\thecor`.  In your case putting `\show\thecor` after the definition reveals

> ```
> > \thecor=macro:
> ->\thechapter .\arabic {cor}.
> l.9 \show\thecor
> ```

in the `log` file.  So the format you wish for can be obtained by replacing `\arabic` by `\Roman` here as follows

```
 \renewcommand*{\thecor}{\thechapter.\Roman{cor}}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[name=Corollary,numberwithin=chapter]{cor}
\renewcommand*{\thecor}{\thechapter.\Roman{cor}}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter]{lemma}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{theorem}
  A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{cor}
  A corollary.
\end{cor}

\begin{lemma}
  A lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
  Another theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```